# Error when using headless Chrome in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scraping something on the website. For the sake of getting the dynamic content on the website, I turn to selenium. But when I try to use **headless Chrome**, the terminal outputs the following warning/error message every time I open the page.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9234/devtools/browser/3b04bcfa-0f81-4131-813f-9db6f63711fa
[1002/145548.271:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is
[1002/145548.391:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.Cr
eateCommandBuffer.
[1002/145549.272:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", sour
ce:  (0)
```

Moreover, when I try to scrape in **Google Colab**, the result doesn't seem to be nice and even unstable. That's the length of the scraping content isn't the same even when I try it successively. When I put the same code to run in local with **non-headless** Chrome seems to be better. The setting is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Before I run in Google Colab. I run the below command mentioned in the community.

```
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium
```

System

```
OS: windows 10 + python 3.7 + Chrome 93.0.x + selenium 1.26.6
```

Comment: Why are you calling maximise_window when you've specified headless?

Comment: @BrutusForcus Thanks for your reply. I set this first to maximize the loaded content of my page when I try **non-headless** Chrome. Sorry for that, I forget to delete it when I turn to **headless**. I delete it, but the issue stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of scraping data from a [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?.tsrc=applewf) and going through some of the content on the left-hand side of the webpage where it says "Summary":

```
import time as time
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!which chromedriver
!pip install selenium
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
!pip install page_objects
import page_objects
from page_objects import PageObject, PageElement
time.sleep(1)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options = options)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?.tsrc=applewf')
open('source.html', 'w').write(driver.page_source)
parent_tab = driver.current_window_handle
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for i in links:
  if 'Summary' in i.get_attribute('text'):
    if 'Bid' in driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text:
      print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
```